# Как убрать элемент с сайта при мобильном разрешении экрана?

Tags: css, адаптивная-верстка

Использую свойство

```
@media (max-width: 800px) {
  #nav-arrows a.nav-right {display: none;}
}
```

оно работает если я пишу это в style.css на локальном сервере
на хостинге ничего не происходит?
В чем может быть проблема?

Comment: Почитайте про [mcve]

Comment: Ctrl+F5 нажми..

Comment: попрбуйте такой вариант @media screen and (max-width: 800px)